# RegEx match first occurrence before keyword

Tags: regex, replace, match, find-occurrences

I have the following string:

```
<ul><li><span>some words here.</span></li><li><span>other words here.</span></li><li><span>Code: 55555.</span></li></ul>
```

My goal is to remove this part from the string, the set of li tags which contain "code" keyword:

```
<li><span>Code: 55555.</span></li>
```

I am trying to write a RegEx that will help me match and replace my substring. 
Text in between `<li></li>` might vary but it will always have the keyword "Code". This is what I have so far:

```
<li>(.*)code:(.*?)<\/li>
```

The problem is, it matches from the first `<li>` tag and I want it to match starting from the `<li>` tag which is right before our keyword "code".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can there be nested `<li>` items within `<li><span>Code: 55555.</span></li>`?

Comment: nope, there isn't any nesting within.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<li>(?:.(?!</li>))+Code:(?:.*?)</li>`

- Match `<li>` literally
- Followed by any number of characters where the literal `</li>` doesn't match (this ensures the match will start only at the relevant `<li>`)
- Followed by the literal `Code:`
- Followed by any number of characters (non-greedy) until the literal `</li>` is matched

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO5nQ5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex groups for that, so your regex would be something like that:

r'(<\li>(.*)code:(.*?)</li>){1,}'

This regex will match more than 1 occurrence of string which has format <\li>(.*)code:(.*?)</li>.

I guess this might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> (.*)(<li>.*span.*<\/li>)(.*)
> ```

The RegEx provided by Tim Biegeleisen works just fine. If you want to make sure the word "Code" exists, just replace 'span' with 'Code', like:

```
(.*)(<li>.*Code.*<\/li>)(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

[a-z|A-Z]*[Cc]ode: [0-9|.]+[a-z|A-Z]*

Here the keyword "Code" is made mandatory in the regex

Comment: "<li><span>[a-z|A-Z]*[Cc]ode: [0-9|\.]+[a-z|A-Z]*</span></li>"